# href links are not opening in master.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

given below code is in my master template and link under href is not opening but given link is showing by holding on `<LI> item`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" class="scroll">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#faculties" class="scroll">Faculties</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="scroll">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="scroll">Login</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#mail" class="scroll">Mail Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show the `master.blade.php`

Comment: Your links look inaccurate. For example, the href for services should be something lik `href={{ url('/services') }}`. Please show your full code for master and route

Answer (score 0):

If you have a route pointing to your homepage you can call it out

```
{{ route('route_name') }}
```

Or you call a blade view by url() function.

The same way you used for login href bro :))